# How can i open an application in specific places on my monitors, with Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

This is what i have pieced together, and i can't understand why it doesn't work.
The meaning of the script is that it should open google-chrome, and place it at the right side of the screen.

I ain't the best at powershell, so i hope that you guys can help me understand why is doesn't work. And help me find a solution.

```
$source = @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace KeyboardSend
{
    public class KeyboardSend
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
        private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
        private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
        public static void KeyDown(Keys vKey)
        {
            keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
        }
        public static void KeyUp(Keys vKey)
        {
            keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -ReferencedAssemblies "System.Windows.Forms"

Function Win ($Key)
{
    [KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("LWin")
    [KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("$Key")
    [KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyUp("LWin")

}


$chrome = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' 
$url = 'www.google.com'
& $chrome $url

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("LWin")
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{RIGHT}')


[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyUp("LWin")
```

Answer (score 1):

#1: You seem to be trying multiple things to do the same function. E.g. the `Win()` function, the `$wshell.SendKeys`, and the `KeyUp/KeyDown` from C#.

To clean this up, we'll introduce a simple new C# function to replace SendKeys:

```
public static void KeyPress(Keys vKey)
{
    KeyDown(vKey);
    KeyUp(vKey);
}
```

So now you can send your `Win + Right` like so:

```
KeyDown("LWin");
KeyPress("Right");
KeyUp("LWin");
```

---

#2: To send keys to applications, Windows requires that the app window is ready and active in the foreground. If you try to send too fast after executing, it won't work. If you try while the window is in the background, it won't work.

To handle this, we'll utilise the Windows API:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
public static bool SetForeground(string processName)
{
    Process proc = null;
    var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
    // Wait until a window handle is available.
    // Some apps like Chrome spawns MANY processes, but only
    // one will have a MainWindowHandle.
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (proc == null)
            proc = procs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);
    }).Wait(2000); // Quit if none found in this time
    if (proc == null) return false;
    SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
    return true;
}
```

And you can just use it like so:

```
SetForeground("chrome");
```

---

Now the full code.

**NOTE:** I'm using `msedge` as I don't have chrome installed. You should be able to find the 2 references to edge and replace them both with `chrome`.

```
$source = @"
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace KeyboardSend
{
public class KeyboardSend
{
    private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
    private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    public static bool SetForeground(string processName)
    {
        Process proc = null;
        var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
        // Wait until a window handle is available.
        // Some apps like Chrome spawns MANY processes, but only
        // one will have a MainWindowHandle.
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (proc == null)
                proc = procs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);
        }).Wait(2000); // Quit if none found in this time
        if (proc == null) return false;
        SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
        return true;
    }
    public static void KeyDown(Keys vKey)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    }
    public static void KeyUp(Keys vKey)
    {
        keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
    public static void KeyPress(Keys vKey)
    {
        KeyDown(vKey);
        KeyUp(vKey);
    }
}
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -ReferencedAssemblies "System.Windows.Forms"

# Start your app
$chrome = 'msedge.exe' #change to chrome
$url = 'about:blank'
Start-Process -PassThru $chrome $url 

# Wait for window to be available and pull to front.
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::SetForeground("msedge"); #change to chrome
# May wanna wrap in an IF statement in case it failed.

# Send your keys
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyDown("LWin");
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyPress("Right");
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyUp("LWin");

# You may need to send escape if Windows10 asks you 
# what you want to snap to the other side.
sleep -Milliseconds 200
[KeyboardSend.KeyboardSend]::KeyPress("Escape");
```